# Specifying Elasticsearch version to 2.3.1 on Travis

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, travis-ci

I am trying to update our Travis.ml file to work with our recent upgrade of ES to 2.3.1 and cannot seem to get it to properly pass / build indexes. I am using the following method to install elastic search to the container ([source](https://github.com/inveniosoftware/invenio-search/issues/58)):

```
- mkdir /tmp/elasticsearch
- wget -O - https://download.elasticsearch.org/elasticsearch/release/org/elasticsearch/distribution/tar/elasticsearch/${ES_VERSION}/elasticsearch-${ES_VERSION}.tar.gz | tar xz --directory=/tmp/elasticsearch --strip-components=1
- /tmp/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -d -D es.path.data=/tmp -D es.index.store.type=memory -D es.discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled=false
```

And so after doing this when I run `curl http://localhost:9200/` in the Travis build I always get the following response in the logs:

```
{
  "name" : "Garrison Kane",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "2.3.1",
    "build_hash" : "bd980929010aef404e7cb0843e61d0665269fc39",
    "build_timestamp" : "2016-04-04T12:25:05Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "5.5.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Which is what I want. However, when I go to build the actual indexes in the Travis build I get the following error:

```
Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest: [400] {
  "error":{
    "root_cause":[
      {"type":"index_creation_exception",
       "reason":"failed to create index"
      }],
      "type":"illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason":"Unknown store type [memory]"
    },
  "status":400
}
```

So when I have tried googling this the small amount of information I could find about it lead me to believe that the cause is two elastic search nodes running in tandem in the container. To verify this I simply added `elasticsearch -v` to my travis.ml file and would always get `Version: 1.4.0, Build: bc94bd8/2014-11-05T14:26:12Z, JVM: 1.7.0_76` which appears to be the default version that Travis tries to install at the start (regardless of whether or not I add ES as a service in the travis.yml file).

I have tried explicitly killing all running instances of elasticsearch with `apt-get purge elasticsearch` before I try to install v 2.3.1 with the approach above, but when I tried that it wouldn't allow me to curl localhost at 9200 since it apparently just wasn't running.

### tl;dr

My question is this: How can I both specify the version of ES to run in a Travis container (a version that does not exist as a supported package) and how I do kill the default ES process on the container without disabling elasticsearch altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to create an in-memory index. In memory indices have been deprecated in Elasticsearch 2.x, simply remove the `memory` from the `index.store.type` setting.